# Deleting files from previous month with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am creating weekly backup files via PowerShell. Every month I want to delete all the backup files from the previous month.
Currently my file names look like this:

```
08.18.2015_username_ChromeBookmarks
```

Where the date is created using the `get-date` cmdlet.
Which is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Probably this would help:

```
 ls . | ? -Property Name -Match "0?$((get-date).Month-1)\.\d{1,2}\.\d{2,4}_.*" | del
```

Also caution should be taken if this is the required directory. See `pushd` and `popd` to change current directory temporary.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that's a little easier to read, but it is using the actual creation time of the file and not just the filename to get the date.

```
Get-ChildItem -File | ?{ $_.CreationTime.Month -eq $((Get-Date).AddMonths(-1)).Month } | Remove-Item
```

Comment: @campbell.nw This is sadly not working. It is not deleting the files. If I understand correcly, this will also only delete the files exactly one month ago from the current date.

Comment: `$((Get-Date).AddMonths(-1)).Month` rather. Otherwise the comparison fails during all of January :)

Comment: We are now in the 9th month, but none of the files from the 8th month are being deleted?

Comment: @RyanHillhouse If you run it without piping to remove-item, is it finding the files you expect? You may need to be specific with what path get-childitem is using. (ie. specify an absolute path)

Comment: It's working! I specified the path and now it's working perfectly

Comment: That's great! Also, as I'm sure you already noticed, it will delete all files from previous month, not just files exactly a month from today, since we are comparing only months and not the entire date.